# AJAX pagination, update current page

Tags: php, ajax

I created a numeric pagination that loads the data via AJAX.

This is the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      load_data(1); 
     
      function load_data(page)  
      {          
        $.ajax({
                url:"pagination2.php",  
                method:"POST", 
                data:{page:page},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#load_data').html(data);
                } 
           }); 
      }  

      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(event) 
        {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            var page = $(this).attr("id"); 
            load_data(page);
            //Now push PAGE to URL
            window.history.pushState({page}, `Selected: ${page}`, `${'page=' +  page}`)
            return event.preventDefault(); 
      });
            window.addEventListener('popstate', e => {
            var page = $(this).attr("id");
            load_data(e.state.page);
            console.log('popstate error!');
    });
    
 });
```

The code works, but when I refresh the page the data are loaded again from the first page. [test_ajax](http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/2020_pagination_1/public/page=5)

Ex: If I click the button that loads the page 2 when I refresh the page the data are displayed from the page 1.

There is a way to remain on the same page even after the page refresh?

**pagination2.php**

```
<?php 

$rowperpage = 10;

$page = 1;
if($_REQUEST['page'] > 1)
{
  $p = (($_REQUEST['page'] - 1) * $rowperpage);
  $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
}
else
{
  $p = 0;
}

?>


<?php   
 $visible = $visible ?? true;
  
$products_count = count_all_products(['visible' => $visible]);    
      
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ";
$sql .= "WHERE visible = true ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY position ASC ";
$sql .= "LIMIT ".$p.", ".$rowperpage."";  
        
$product_set = find_by_sql($sql);
      
$product_count = mysqli_num_rows($product_set);
    
if($product_count == 0) {
      echo "<h1>No products</h1>";
      }

while($run_product_set = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product_set)) { ?>

    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px; class="small">

      <a href="<?php echo url_for('/show.php?id=' . h(u($run_product_set['id'])));   ?>">
          <img src="staff/images/<?php echo h($run_product_set['filename']); ?> " width="150">
        </a>

      <p><?php echo h($run_product_set['prod_name']); ?></p>

    </div>

    <?php }

    mysqli_free_result($product_set);
      
?>
<section id="pagination">
                           
    
<?php
    
$url = url_for('index_all.php');
                        
if($_REQUEST['page'] > 1)
    { 
      $page_nb = $_REQUEST['page'];
    }
    else
    {
      $page_nb = 1;
    }                       
                            
$check = $p + $rowperpage;
$prev_page = $page_nb - 1;

$limit = $products_count / $rowperpage;
    //echo $limit;
    //exit;
$limit = ceil($limit);
$current_page = $page_nb;
    
if($page_nb > 1) {
    //echo "<a href='index_all.php?page=".$prev_page."'>Back</a>";
    echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;'  id='".$prev_page."'>Back</span>";

}
    
if ( $products_count > $check ) {

    for ( $i = max( 1, $page_nb - 5 ); $i <= min( $page_nb + 5, $limit ); $i++ ) {
        if ( $current_page == $i ) {
            echo "<span class=\"selected\">{$i}</span>";
        } else {
            echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$i."'>".$i."</span>"; 
        }
      }
    }       
    
if ($products_count > $check) { 
$next_page = $page_nb + 1;  
    echo "<span class='pagination_link' style='cursor:pointer;' id='".$next_page."'>Next</span>";
    
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Usually, `window.history.pushState` should change the URL in the location bar

Comment: @Nico Please `window.history.pushState` yes true, that works, but after refresh (F5) it's go to page. 1.

Comment: @Nico Please if you want, I cant send you zip code.

Comment: `page` is an `$_GET` argument to the URL, but you probably only respond to the `$_POST` argument from the AJAX call. Simply replace `$_POST` by `$_REQUEST` and it will respond to both.

Comment: @ KIKO Software `$_POST` by `$_REQUEST` done, but the same - after refresh  go to page 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the document is ready you use `load_data(1);`

That's wrong because if someone refreshes at page 5 it starts anyway from page 1.
Check the current page everytime you refresh.
The code should be something like this:

```
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url_parts = url_string.split('/');
var piece = url_parts[url_parts.length -1]; //get last part of url (it should be page=n)
var page;
if(piece.substring(0, 5) === 'page=') {
   page = parseInt(piece.substr(5));
} else { //if it's the first time you landed in the page you haven't page=n
   page = 1;
}
load_data(page);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but where to paste the code? To `click`?

Comment: Right after  $(document).ready(function(){ . Delete that load_data(1) and try the code

Comment: `http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/2020_pagination_1/public/index2.php` `Uncaught ReferenceError: url_part is not defined`

Comment: because I forgot an s, sorry. In var piece = url_part[ change it with url_parts[
Or just copy paste again. I fixed it.

Comment: I corrected `url_part` to `url_parts` `http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/2020_pagination_1/public/page=6` now everything seems to be working.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would never have solved it myself.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Is there any direct contact to you here in this forum?

Comment: I have one last question, could you please explain your code for me to understand?

Comment: Code explanation:
I take the url and I split it into pieces so I can work later with the last part. Then I check the last part. If it's the first time I land in the page the last part would be public, otherwise it will be page=number. In the if I check if it starts with page= so I know you're currently in a different page. That being checked I take the number. I use substring because if you have more then 9 pages the number will have 2 digits instead of 1. If it doesn't start with page= then you want to load the page 1

Comment: Btw there aren't DM here

Comment: Can you take a look at this: `http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/2020_pagination_3/public/deco.php`, I changed the file name `index.php` to `deco.php` after that  'Not Found index.php' why is this happening?

Comment: I didn't understand. Before renaming you were given the error 'Not found Index.php'?

Comment: Check please this link `http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/2020_pagination_3/public/page=4`

Comment: in this place `2020_pagination_3` I changed `index.php` to `deco.php`

Comment: Have you done something with php? Did you move the index.php? What was the last thing you did?

Comment: I changed `index.php` to `deco.php` because I wanted to rename. And I thought the link would look like this `deco.php/page=2`

Comment: You should create a folder named deco/ and add there the index.php. This is because the name index.php is hidden by default in the url. So you need an index.php file anyway if you want to manipulate the url like that. Or you shohuld create and use some api, but it's not worth it if you have to do just that thing